# how to compare values from different columns and insert data using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, stored-procedures

I have the following SQL which picks the winning ticket from my lotto table:

```
SELECT TOP 1 LOTTOID, VAL0, VAL1, VAL2, VAL3, VAL4, VAL5 FROM tblLotto ORDER BY NEWID()
```

I now need to write a query which will check for each value and if it matches 3 numbers from either columns then insert the ticket ID into a table called `tblWinners_3`

and if it matches 4 balls then insert the ticket ID into the table `tblWinners_4` etc etc

I was thinking of doing:

```
SELECT TOP 1 LOTTOID, VAL0, VAL1, VAL2, VAL3, VAL4, VAL5 
FROM tblLotto 
WHERE VAL0 IN (SELECT VAL0 FROM tblLotto)
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

The problem is that `SELECT VAL0 FROM tblLotto` will return multiple rows so by default it will grab the first one from the list and therefore not an effective way to compare and search.

```
**tblLotto** contains all the tickets people have purchased.
**tblDraw** is the lotto draw 
**tblWinners_3** contain the IDs for tickets who have matched 3 balls.
```

Comment: Question is not clear.  Pretty sure WHERE VAL0 IN (SELECT VAL0 FROM tblLotto) will return true every time.

Comment: How do you know what the winning numbers are? Are these stored in another table? Please provide further details.

Comment: My question is how do i return the winning tickets who matched 3 numbers in the Lotto?

Comment: Can you not just make a few assumptions? One user who posted an answer seems to know what i am talking about. why dont you?

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this?

```
SELECT LOTTOID,
    CASE WHEN VAL0=(SELECT VAL0 FROM tblDraw) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN VAL1=(SELECT VAL1 FROM tblDraw) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN VAL2=(SELECT VAL2 FROM tblDraw) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN VAL3=(SELECT VAL3 FROM tblDraw) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN VAL4=(SELECT VAL4 FROM tblDraw) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN VAL5=(SELECT VAL5 FROM tblDraw) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    AS totalValues
INTO #tempWinners
FROM tblLotto 

INSERT INTO tblWinners_3
SELECT LOTTOID
FROM #tempWinners
WHERE totalValues = 3 AND LOTTOID not in (SELECT LOTTOID FROM tblWinners_3)

INSERT INTO tblWinners_4
SELECT LOTTOID
FROM #tempWinners
WHERE totalValues = 4 AND LOTTOID not in (SELECT LOTTOID FROM tblWinners_4)

INSERT INTO tblWinners_5
SELECT LOTTOID
FROM #tempWinners
WHERE totalValues = 5 AND LOTTOID not in (SELECT LOTTOID FROM tblWinners_5)

DROP TABLE #tempWinners
```

NOTE: I'm supposing your tblDraw has the values in val0, val1, ....
If that's not the case, for instance, if it follows this configuration:

```
CREATE TABLE tblDraw (
    extractedNumber int
)
```

Then you'd use `VALx in (SELECT extractedNumber from tblDraw)`

Comment: Thanks!!! The only down side to my data structure is that the numbers dont have to be in order therefore matching them up for `val0` vs `val0` wont work with CASE.

Comment: it would have to be something like: `VAL0=(SELECT VAL0 FROM tblDraw WHERE val0 =(select * from tblDraw))`

Comment: In that case your best option is to use `in`. You just do `CASE WHEN VAL0 in (SELECT * from tblDraw) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` and just the same replacement for all the other VAL1, VAL2, ...